# Continue native android in Xamarin

Tags: android, eclipse, xamarin, google-play, software-distribution

I have a "normal" Android app, made in Eclipse/java, published in Play Store, already at version 3.x, all works fine.

Now I am thinking to move the project to Xamarin/c#, and make the 4.0 there.

My question, what should I take care/be aware, that this change should be a natural continuation of the 3.x from Google Play/Users perspective?
So that I could simple upload the APK made by Xamarin to Dev Console as a new version upgrade, and not as a new App.

Like:

1. Existing signing key should be reused in Xamarin?
2. Package name (java <> xamarin c#) must be the same?
3. ???

Thanks

Answer (score -1, accepted):

There is absolutely no difference for google what language you natively used to write an app. By the way Xamarin will be compiled to java before packaging into apk. 
Also Xamarin uses the installed Android SDK and installed Java SDK you have used before to sign the apk and compile the app. It also is going to use same keys so sign the apk.
So no worries, keep same package name and you're good for the update.

Comment: So sign with the current key and keep the package name - that's it.

Comment: `Xamarin will be compiled to java before packaging into apk`:  Xamarin does **NOT** transcompile C# to Java. It does create generate Java wrappers for Java.Lang.Object based objects so they can be passed across the Java<->C# bridge, but your C# code (CIL-based) is running under the Mono runtime and the Java bytecode is running under the Java VM (Dalvik / ART)